# Convert a set of bytes into a string in python

Tags: python-3.x, binary

I have the following byte array :

```
b'\x80UTI\xfc\x7f\x00\x00'
```

I want to convert it to :

```
'\x80UTI\xfc\x7f\x00\x00'
```

How can i do that in python ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert bytes to a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/606191/convert-bytes-to-a-string)

Answer (score 0):

Convert it to string with `str()` and then some string manipulation

```
>>> x = b'\x80UTI\xfc\x7f\x00\x00'
>>> y = str(x)[1:].strip("'")
>>> print(y)
x80UTI\xfc\x7f\x00\x00
```

Comment: Don't parse the structure. There are [better methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/606191/convert-bytes-to-a-string) -- also, flag as a duplicate next time.

Comment: @Frank This is not the correct way to converting a byte to string. Use decode instead. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/606191/convert-bytes-to-a-string